# Asp.net mvc project give me internal server error after publisihng

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

after publishing asp.net mvc project i noticed that in localhost in debug mode when call link http://localhost:56881/CPanel/login?role=form
it return login view normally .

but after publishing it when try to call http://domainname.com/CPanel/login?role=form
it gave me 500 - Internal server error.

```
//Login Action >> CPanel Controller 
public ActionResult login() 
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult login(FormCollection customer, string ReturnUrl) 
{
    ViewBag.isError = false;
    if (Session["SystemAdmin"] == null)
    {
        var u = new Egx.EgxBusiness.Inventory.User() { USER_NAME = customer["EMAIL_ADDR"] }.Search();
        Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(u[0].PASSWORD, customer["password"]);
        if (u.Count > 0 && Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(u[0].PASSWORD, customer["password"]))
        {
            var c = new Customers() { EMAIL_ADDR = customer["EMAIL_ADDR"] }.Search();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(c[0].CUST_NAME, false);
            Session["_customer"] = c[0];
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl) && ReturnUrl.Length > 1 && ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !ReturnUrl.StartsWith("/\\")) { return Redirect(ReturnUrl); }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.isError = true;
            return View();
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        var c = new Customers() { EMAIL_ADDR = customer["EMAIL_ADDR"] }.Search();
        if (c.Count == 0) { c = new Customers() {CUST_CODE=customer["EMAIL_ADDR"] }.Search(); }
        if (c.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["_customer"] = c[0];
                 return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.isError = true;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Login View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("login", "CPanel", new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], role = "form" }))
{
     if (Request.QueryString["r"] != null) { <input type="hidden" value="@Request.QueryString["r"]" name="r"/> }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input  class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="EMAIL_ADDR" type="text" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="" @Html.Raw(EgxNMWeb.AuthSystemAdmin.isSystemAdmin()? "disabled":string.Empty)>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
            </label>
        </div>
        <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" />
        @Html.Raw(EgxNMWeb.AuthSystemAdmin.isSystemAdmin()? "<a href="+Url.Action("Index","Finance")+">ماليات</a>":string.Empty)
}
```

Comment: Do any other pages work properly?

Comment: yes every thing goes fine

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean on solution and build it again and publish it. Also, set custom error mode to off. If you can give us a specific error we might be able to help you out more. Also make sure authentication mode on your local machine matches the authentication mode on the server you are publishing too.

Comment: i tried to clean solution an rebuild but nothing changed :(

Comment: and i noticed that ReturnUrl doesn't work on remote server but works fine in localhost !!

Comment: Did you change the custom error mode in your web config file? That should give you a more specific error. Try that and let me know what the specific error is.

Comment: Also I'm guessing if other pages are working and only login view is not working it may be that your view file is not getting published correctly or your authentication mode on your remote server is not set right. By authentication mode I mean windows, anonymous etc

Comment: i changed custom error mode to On but it gives me the same error 
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: How should i set authentication mode ?

Comment: hmm I'm surprised that it's not giving you a detailed error. Try this and this should give you a detailed error - Open up iis manager in your remote serve, locate your login file/view, right click on it and click browse. It should still fail, but will give you a detailed error. To enable forms authentication please refer to this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc771077(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: Try browsing your view from iis directly before you change authentication mode.